# Columns.Add() vs new DataColumn()

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I feel confused on how to insert a new column on a table, and what's the difference between `Columns.Add()` and `new DataColumn()`?

```
DataTable student = new DataTable("Students");
student.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));


DataColumn id = new DataColumn("ID");
id.DataType = typeof(int);
student.Columns.Add(id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataColumnCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy.aspx) is just short-cut for creating column and adding it. As MSDN says:

> Creates and adds a DataColumn object that has the specified name and
>   type to the DataColumnCollection.

And this is how it implemented:

```
public DataColumn Add(string columnName, Type type)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, type);
    this.Add(column);
    return column;
}
```

As you can see, internally it creates new instance of `DataColumn` and adds it to itself.

NOTE: You can use `DataColumn` constructor which accepts column data type as second parameter. Thus your second sample could look like:

```
student.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
```

But anyway, I think first 'short-cut' option is more readable and compact. You might want to use latter approach if you already have some columns, or if you have columns of custom type inherited from `DataColumn`.

Comment: It is obvious that you are right but on the rush i couldn't find a reference for that being just a short hand. However the doc says ["Creates and adds a DataColumn object to the DataColumnCollection"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.add.aspx)

Comment: @isi yes, I have already added this MSDN quote. As it says, `Add` method is a short-cut for creating and adding column, because it creates and adds column

Comment: hehe on the rush, my bad ;)